# What does the Markov assumption say about the history of state sequences?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, math, definitions, norvig-russell, markov-property

Does the Markov assumption say that the conditional probability of the next state only depends on the current state or does it say that the conditional probability depends on a fixed finite number of previous states?

As far as I understand from [the related Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property#Introduction), the probability of the next state $s'$ to appear only depends on the current state $s$.

However, in the book "Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach" by Russell and Norvig, on page 568, they say: "**Markov assumption** — that the current state depends on only a *finite fixed number* of previous states".

To me, the second statement seems contradictory to the first, because it may mean that a state can depend on the history of states as long as the number is fixed a finite. For example, the current state depended on the last state and the state before the last state, which is 2 sequential previous states (a finite number of states).

Is Markov assumption and Markov property the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [stochastic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process) has the [Markov property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property) if the probability distribution of future states conditioned on both the present and past states depends only on the present state or, more formally, the following equality holds.

$$
p(s_{t+1} \mid s_{t}, s_{t-1:1}) = p(s_{t+1} \mid s_{t}), \forall t
$$

The [hidden Markov model (HMM)](https://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/Reprints/tutorial%20on%20hmm%20and%20applications.pdf) is an example of a model where the Markov property is often assumed to hold. In other words, the Markov assumption is made in the case of the HMM.

There are also the [variable-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-order_Markov_model) (or higher-order) Markov models, where the future state can depend on the previously $n$ states or, more formally, the following equality holds.

$$
p(s_{t+1} \mid s_{t}, s_{t-1:1}) = p(s_{t+1} \mid s_{t:t-n}), \forall t
$$

In this context, a hidden Markov model is called a **first-order** Markov model ($n=0$). Therefore, there can also be second-order ($n=1$), third-order ($n=2$), etc., Markov models. In fact, there are also [higher-order hidden Markov models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.12201.pdf).

To conclude, the expressions *Markov property* and *Markov assumption* are not exactly interchangeable. The Markov property is an attribute that a stochastic process can be assumed to possess. In that case, the Markov assumption is made. The expression *Markov property* usually refers to a first-order Markov property, but it can more generally refer to a higher-order Markov property.